# How to match mark check box from two column?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, checkbox, webforms

i am trying to match check box checked values from two side like

```
chkLastFirst         chkThisFirst 
chkLastSecond        chkThisSecond 
chkLastThird         chkThisThird
chkLastFour          chkThisFour
```

Remember text value of both column check box is same like ,

```
First    First
Second   Second
Third    Third
Four     Four
```

now i want to know checkbox from second column is checked "chkThisFirst" so is check box from first column is also cheked or not "chkLastFirst" matching second column check box with first column check box how many of check boxes are checked ?

in simple words if i mark 2 checkbox in second column so either that same check box in fist column are mark or not or how much check box are mark in first column out of mark checkbox of second column

Hopes you under stand if not then ask me Hopes for your suggestion

Thanks

Comment: Are you saying that if you check the 3rd box in column 1 you want the 3rd checkbox in column 2 to be checked for you?

Comment: no i want to know that if i check 3rd box in second column then i wanna check weather 3rd box in first column is checked or not

Comment: or if i check 2nd and 3rd box in second column and 1st 2nd 3rd box in first column then match box of second column from first column weather 2nd and 3rd are checked in first column or not and how much are checked

Answer (score 0):

group them using the name attribute, ie.

```
 <input type="checkbox"  name="first"/> <input type="checkbox" 
 name="first"/>

 <input type="checkbox"  name="second"/> <input type="checkbox" 
 name="second"/>
```

then using JS/JQuery when the one gets clicked, get the other one in the group and see if it is checked.

heres my JsFiddle implementation
http://jsfiddle.net/CbsGN/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("td:nth-child(2) input[type='checkbox']").on('click',function() {
        var nameValue = $(this).attr('name');
        var groupItems = $("[name ='" + nameValue + "']");
        if($(groupItems[1]).is(":checked"))
        {        
            alert($(groupItems[0]).is(":checked"));
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: thanks for your solution actually i want to match chekbox as you are doing in C# code :(

Answer (score 0):

Note: Other posters solutions are probably better, but using this code as reference you should be able to come up with your own solution.

```
$(function () {
$('#column2 input[type=checkbox]').change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        var $matchingBox = $('#column1 input[value=' + $(this).val() + ']');
        if ($matchingBox.is(':checked')) {
            alert('Yep, box' + $matchingBox.parent('label').text() + ' is checked!');
        }
    }
});
});
```

[Link to Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n9W84/)

Comment: Using the server control for this is the most inefficient way on the planet. You're doing a full page refresh on each radio button change. To be blunt, it's completely stupid to do that.